# Contentcontrol doesn't find my datatemplate it's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I'm using WPF, MVVM & PRISM.
I got a datatemplate in my View linked to a ViewModel UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel cause the page were this code is included is linked to another ViewModel and I want the Button to have UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel as ViewModel.

**The datacontext of this page is UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel but I want the SaveButton to use the ViewModel UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel**

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/RFPModuleResources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SaveButton" DataType="{x:Type vm:UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}">
                <Button Command="{Binding SaveRFPCommand}">Save</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SaveButton}"/>
   <Button Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}">Close</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Although the SaveButton displays but don't reacts on my command. 
Do I forget something or is there another way to solve this? 
Thanks in advance ;) !

=================================================================================

**EDIT:**

So I made some changes but it still doesn't work.

Code example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/RFPModuleResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="SaveButton" DataType="{x:Type vm:UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding SaveRFPCommand}">Save</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I set this property in the ViewModel of the page

```
public UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel MySaveVM { get; set; }
```

My stackpanel looks now like this:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MySaveVM}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SaveButton}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}">Close</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So just to be clear. Do you ever set the DataContext of your view? i.e. Is the DataContext set to an instance of UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel?

Comment: The page is a usercontrol a tabitem and the datacontext is set with this code:    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel}">
<v:UC2002_RFPBeheren_TabItemProjectinfo_View />
                    </DataTemplate>

Comment: So if the DataContext is your ViewModel then the answer I put where you set the Content of the ContentControl to "{Binding}" should work.

Comment: I don't want the main Datacontext of the page to be the datacontext of the button. I want a diff datacontext on the button than the main.

Comment: So the DataContext of the StackPanel above is UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel. And presumably that has a CloseTabCommand property since that is what you are binding on the Button sibling to the ContentControl in question. In the template you are using for the ContentControl, you are binding to a property named SaveRFPCommand. What object defines that property? If that is also on the UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel then you do want to use that as the DataContext. If that is off a subobject on that then you would bind to the property that returns that subobject.

Comment: SaveRFPCommand is a DelegateCommand and I want it to set in UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel like al other stuff on the page I want them to have datacontext UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what happens if you set your UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel instance as the content for the ContentPresenter?

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyUV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}"/>
```

the DataTemplate just say how your Viewmodel should be displayed, but you have to set the DataContext or Binding to the instance of your viewmodel.

EDIT:

example

```
 public class VMFoo
 {
     public UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel MySaveVM {get; set;}
 }
```

xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/RFPModuleResources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SaveButton" DataType="{x:Type vm:UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}">
                <Button Command="{Binding SaveRFPCommand}">Save</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <x:local VMFoo/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding MySaveVM}"/>
   <Button Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}">Close</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT: Small working sample

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}">
            <Button Command="{Binding SaveRFPCommand}">Save</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid> 
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <WpfApplication1:VMFoo/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MySaveVM}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}">Close</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodels

```
public class VMFoo
{
    public VMFoo()
    {
        this.MySaveVM = new UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel();
    }
    public UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel MySaveVM { get; set; }
}

public class UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel
{
    private DelegateCommand _save;
    public ICommand SaveRFPCommand
    {
        get{if(this._save==null)
        {
            this._save = new DelegateCommand(()=>MessageBox.Show("success"),()=>true);
        }
            return this._save;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I changed it to <ContentControl Content="{Binding UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SaveButton}"/> but it still doesn't comes in the breakpoint of my ViewModel

Comment: you dont need the ContentTemplate, but you need a INSTANCE of your viewmodel. and this INSTANCE should be bind as the Content for your contentcontrol. so if your datacontext is VMFoo, then you need a public property of type UV2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel in your VMFoo you can bind to.

Comment: I made the changes check my question I know what you mean but something is still wrong I guess

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way that ContentControl's work. It is assumed that the things in the ContentTemplate are related to the Content and so the DataContext is set to the Content and therefore that is the DataContext that the button within the template has access to. You haven't specified a Content so the value is null and so the DataContext is explicitly set to null. You can see this in a basic example. One thing you can do is to bind the Content of the ContentControl to the DataContext - see the last contentcontrol in the example.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="Foo">  
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="withBtn">
      <Button Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <Button Content="{Binding}" />
  <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource withBtn}" />
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource withBtn}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM you must expose some instance of UC2002_RFPBeheren_ViewModel within your  UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel to bind against. Either as a property, or an item of a collection that is a property.

Everything in the view must be ultimately accessible from the ViewModel that is your data context (UC2002_RFPBeheren_ProjectInfo_ViewModel)

Comment: Lose the DataContext="MySaveVM" on the button declaration. The template's context is already set to MySaveVM in your binding on the ContentControl. You should be able to see binding errors in your output window which help diagnosing things like this.

Comment: Don't got mutch help from my output dialog it says: The thread '<No Name>' (0x1fbc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).